# Recombining chunked data in Python not working properly?

Tags: python, chunks

I have a file that is 1.1GB. I need to transfer it to a s3 bucket in a different AWS environment. Due to permission restrictions that can't be changed, I can't use aws s3 cp to move the file or just upload it in s3. My only option is a code pipeline that can only upload files of 25MB or less. So, I split the file into smaller files using the command:

```
split -b 23m file.dat chunkfolder/newfiles
```

After splitting the files, I am testing out how to recombine them to get it all as one dataframe. After reading in the original 1.1GB file, I have a shape of (3958282, 60). To get this I use the following code, where dtypes is a dictionary of the data type each column should be:

```
file = '/to/path/file.dat'
data = open(file, "rb")
dt = data.read()
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(dt), sep = '|', dtype = dtypes)
print('orig shape:', df.shape)
```

Then, to read in the chunked files I do:

```
#reading in first chunk with col names
file = '/to/path/chunkfolder/newfilesaa'
data = open(file, "rb")
dt = data.read()

full_df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(dt), sep = '|', dtype = dtypes)
print('full_df shape:', full_df.shape)
print(full_df.head())

 #reading in rest of files
filepath = '/to/path/chunkfolder'
files = os.listdir(filepath)

for file in files:
    if file != 'newfilesaa':
        print(file)
        data = open(filepath + '/' + file, "rb")
        dt = data.read()

        df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(dt), sep = '|', header = None, names = list(full_df), dtype = dtypes)
        full_df = full_df.append(df)
print('combined shape:', full_df.shape)
print('combined: ', full_df.head())
```

But, I now get an error `cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64` from the first file in the in the loop getting read in.

When I don't specify dtype, it goes through and the full_df has a shape of (3958326, 60). This is larger than what it should be. And, I get numerous warning errors like:

```
newfilesau
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (11,12,21,23,24,29,32,58) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
newfilesav
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (30,40,42,43,51,58) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

I tried to check which rows don't match using:

```
print(full_df.merge(df,indicator = True, how='outer').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']!='both'])
```

But this gives the error

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

How can I recombine these chunked files to get a dataframe that matches the original(unchunked) dat file? Why am I able to specify dtypes and the original file be read in correctly, but the chunked data can't be read in with dtypes?

Comment: You're not using `split` in a way that will respect the original line boundaries, so your chunks are generally going to start and/or end with a partial line.  Rejoining the chunks before trying to parse them as CSV would be one solution; using `split` in a way that breaks only on line boundaries would also work, but I'm not sure there's a way to guarantee maximum chunk size when doing that.

Comment: Just as an aside, this code doesn't make sense: `dt = data.read(); full_df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(dt), sep = '|', dtype = dtypes)` This should just be `full_df = pd.read_csv(dt, sep='|', dtype=dtypes)`, why create the pointless, intermediate bytes object just to pass to `io.BytesIO`.... *you already had a file object*

Comment: Also, another aside, `full_df = full_df.append(df)` is an anti-pattern with pd.DataFrames. Append the dataframes to a `list` then `pd.concat` that list

Comment: @jasonharper thank you for your comment, it helped me to understand why I was unable to get the dataframe I needed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as to your first comment, I tried removing BytesIO but this produced an error and it couldn't be read in.

Comment: what error? I don't believe you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jasonharper's helpful comment, I realized reading in the chunks with Python wasn't the best solution to the problem. I found a way to recombine the chunked files using Linux. I used:

```
cat chunkfolder/newfiles** > combinedfile
```

And then used the following to confirm the dataframes are the same:

```
full_df.equals(df)
```

Now, I am able to transfer the smaller files and then recombine within the new environment.